# Fetching Data Parallel ly from 2 BLE connected Devices

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Android application is able to connect to 2 devices successfully.
I want to Read Data from 2 BLE devices parallely, is that possible?

Or do I need to change my requirements like Fetch data from one device after completing it, fetch data from another device?

Does Android OS support fetching the Data parallely from 2 BLE devices?

Comment: So, What did you try so far?

Comment: Creating a separate Ghatt connect and running using Async Task i have tried,but its not fetching the data parallely.

Comment: Okay so that's your problem. Provide your code so others can compile and spot the error.

Comment: I want to know do android OS supports scenario like this..,Fetching Data from 2 BLE connected devices parallely.

Comment: any link can u please provide for the parallel pooling of data in BLE.

Comment: @Emil
Please see the discussion topic and don t spam irrelevant links and post unrelated things.
The discussion is about getting data parallely from the BLE devices.
The link which u have given is for connection to BLE device

Comment: Managing multiple connections in Bluetooth is easier if you can enable notifications, rather than reading from each device. If you can, let the Bluetooth device tell you when it has updated data to present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its possible to connect up to 7 devices in parallel. I have successfully performed connection with 5 devices. But I do not recommend you to read data in parallel. Android BLE operation should be performed in the queue for all the devices, otherwise your read operation can be just overwritten by next operation. Take look here, to find more information https://youtu.be/jDykHjn-4Ng